# How does seq force functions?

Tags: haskell, semantics, lazy-evaluation, evaluation

#### Background

This question arises from a challenge Brent Yorgey posed at OPLSS: write a function `f :: (Int -> Int) -> Bool` that distinguishes `f undefined` from `f (\x -> undefined)`. All of our answers either used `seq` or something like bang patterns that desugar into `seq`. For example:

```
f :: (Int -> Int) -> Bool
f g = g `seq` True

*Main> f undefined
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
*Main> f (\x -> undefined)
True
```

The [GHC commentary on `seq`](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Compiler/SeqMagic) says that

```
e1 `seq` e2
```

used to desugar into

```
case e1 of { _ -> e2 }
```

so I tried desugaring manually. It didn't work:

```
f' g = case g of { _ -> True }

*Main> f' undefined
True
*Main> f' (\x -> undefined)
True
```

#### Question

Does this behavior depend on the more complex `seq` described [at the end of the commentary](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Compiler/SeqMagic#Abetterway), and if so, how does it work? Could such an `f` be written without these primitives?

```
x  `seq` e2 ==> case seq# x RW of (# x, _ #) -> e2    -- Note shadowing!
e1 `seq` e2 ==> case seq# x RW of (# _, _ #) -> e2
```

Comment: The GHC commentary is talking about desugaring to Core, where `case e of { ... }` always means "evaluate e".

Comment: `seq` is a language primitive.  If you remove it from the language, you lose the ability to distinguish between those two functions.  Some people would be happy about this :-)

Comment: @Mikhail, @luqui: Shouldn’t those be answers?

Comment: Nah, Mikhail's comment is properly a comment, as it corrects a detail in the question rather than answering it. Luke's comment does largely answer the question, and would make a fine answer given a bit of elaboration.

Comment: @camccann: I thought that Mikhail’s comment directly resolved the asker’s confusion which had led him to ask this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a more higher-level description of STG-machine in [How to make a fast curry: push/enter vs eval/apply](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/eval-apply/eval-apply.ps)

Figure 2 contains rule CASEANY that works for functions. In this paper "is a value" proposition means either:

- it is a saturated constructor application
- it is a function
- it is a partial function application (which is still a function, semantically)

Unboxed values, including literals are treated specially, more information can be found in  [Unboxed values as first class citizens](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/unboxed-values.ps.Z)

All these are implementation details and are hidden inside compiler (GHC). Haskell's case expression doesn't force it's scrutineer, only pattern-matching and seq do.

Answer (score 25):

`seq` cannot be implemented in Haskell. Instead, it is a primitive "hook" into evaluation to weak-head normal form in whatever runtime your Haskell is running on. E.g. on GHC it is compiled to a `case` in GHC Core, which triggers evaluation to the outermost constructor.

Since it can't be implemented in pure Haskell, it is defined (in GHC) as a primop:

```
pseudoop   "seq"
       a -> b -> b
       { Evaluates its first argument to head normal form, and then returns its second
         argument as the result. }
```

Since functions don't have a normal form, `seq` halts evaluation once it reaches one.

Magically available to the compiler. The same goes for other primitives like `par` or `unsafeCoerce`, the `RealWorld` token, `forkOn` and so on. All the useful stuff.

Comment: Does this mean that functions are wrapped in a data constructor once they reach Core: "E.g. on GHC it is compiled to a `case` in GHC Core, which triggers evaluation to the outermost constructor."? I remember from studying the STG machine that a `case` can scrutinize an algebraic type or a primitive, so I suppose this would make sense.

Comment: Sort of. They're represented in the STG machine as closures of a particular type, `FUN` (and friends). http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts/Storage/HeapObjects#FunctionClosures

Comment: My confusion is from this document: http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=67083, where the operational semantics specify a way to return a saturated constructor or an unboxed primitive from a case expression. There's just no rule for returning functions, so I suppose either a) they're wrapped in a constructor or b) such a rule was added later?